# How to prove the formula for the argument of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

$\arg(x + iy) = 2 \cdot \arctan(\dfrac{y}{x + r})$
there is always the mark, this is derived from the 'Half-angle formula'

How can I come from $\tan(\phi) = \tan(\phi + k \pi) = \dfrac{y}{x}$  to $\phi = \arg(x + iy)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the next figure

$\hspace4cm$[image]

Clearly ${\rm Arg}(z)=2\theta=2\arctan\dfrac{y}{x+r}$. Note that this gives the principal determination of the argument of $z\in\mathbb{C} \setminus((-\infty,0]\times\mathbb{R})~$.